# Using C++11 futures: Nested calls of std::async crash: Compiler/Standard library bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, future, mingw-w64

After experiencing crashes when introducing nested calls of std::async in my real program, I was able to reproduce the problem in the following **minimum example**. It crashes often, but not always. Do you see anything what goes wrong, or is it a compiler or standard library bug? Note that the problem remains if `get()` calls to the futures are added.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>

int main (int, char *[])
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> v;
    v.reserve(100);
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        v.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [] () {
            std::async(std::launch::async, [] { });
        }));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**I observe two different kinds of crashes:** (in about every fifth run)

- Termination with *"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."*
- Termination after throwing an instance of *'std::future_error', what():  Promise already satisfied*.

**Environment:**

- Windows 7
- gcc version 4.8.2 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by
  MinGW-W64 project), as provided by Qt 5.3.2
- Command line call: `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread futures.cpp`
- Compiled and run on two independent machines

**Option `-pthread`?**
Could it be that in my environment for some reason the option `-pthread` is silently not taken into account? I observe the same behavior with and without that option.

Comment: have you tried calling get() on each future before allowing the vector to go out of scope?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you run it on Linux or Unix with `strace` or `ltrace` already?

Comment: @RichardHodges, all that would do is turn an implicit wait into an explicit one.

Comment: What kind of crash? Where does it crash? FWIW it's works fine with GCC 4.8.3 on GNU/Linux, but I've never tested GCC's `<future>` on MinGW.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I edited the original question to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. The first error looks like a generic, unhelpful Windows error (oh, unusual ... well I'll go and fix the unusual bits of code!) but the second is very strange and shouldn't be possible when using `std::async`

Comment: Since no one has said so outright, I'll comment that this is a well-formed conforming C++11 program. There's a bug (race) somewhere in the standard library implementation.

Comment: @Casey Thank you for the comment, I included it in the question.

Comment: @Casey, or the native platform runtime, or mingw runtime, since the same standard library implementation works fine on GNU/Linux.

Comment: confirming also works fine on apple clang with libc++. Looks like a library implementation problem.

Comment: Have you tried [filing a bug report](http://mingw.org/Reporting_Bugs) with the MinGW folks yet?

Comment: @JonathanWakely IIRC the first error is what happens when `abort()` is called. Of course, that's not very helpful either...

Comment: What is your compilation command? Have you tried using different threading libraries?

Comment: @diegoperini I added the compilation command to the question. What other threading library can I use? std::async is from the C++11 standard - so you mean I can change the underlying implementation that is used?

Comment: Works fine at MinGW aka `gcc version 4.8.0 (rev2, Built by MinGW-builds project)`

Comment: @borisbn Thanks a lot for trying this platform. Did you try it multiple times, since it does not appear in every run (problem appears on about every fifth run)?

Comment: @SebastianK I tried to run your program 15 times - no crashes. I even wrapped the body of `main` in for-cycle from `0` to `1000` - the same result - no crushes

Comment: @borisbn Thank you for verifying this

Comment: I reported it as a bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/461/

Comment: FYI @SebastianK  Works fine using Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: My money is on a race condition when the future is moved while it's "member" future is being "satisfied"

Comment: What happens if you reduce the number to 5 or something? Starting 200 threads could be an issue. Does the issue still happen if you wait for all before return 0 in main?

Comment: @Makubex Yes, I tried the wait before return 0. This does not change anything. But anyway, I assume the waits to happen implicitly, so there is no need for doing  them explicitly. In case the number of threads is too large, I would expect a std::system_error Exception.

Comment: it works fine on vs-2013...

Comment: Spawning 200 threads on Windows is typically not an issue, because Windows imposes only limitation only by system resources, not something like RLIMIT_NPROC in Linux, and typically you would have enough resources for 200 threads, unless you have really bad PC or very resource-limited VM... But to use threads you need to compile with -pthread. So really it looks like a bug in MinGW c++ runtime. Have you tried to link with the debuggable version of runtime and attempt to run under debugger?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Changing the error message in the question to something other than what the runtime will actually report? That's not a good idea, at all.

Comment: @hvd Are you sure your comment is related to this question?

Comment: @SebastianK Yes, see the edit history. Hossein Narimani Rad made a bogus edit on your question, and I reverted it to your version.

Comment: @hvd Thank you, I didn't consider you were referring to the edit history

Comment: The second error seems interesting. It appears that somehow the program might be trying to put into the same promise twice, which should be a huge no-no.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930700/stdfuture-exception-on-gcc-experimental-implementation-of-c0x It seems to have the same error as yours, and the answer was that the guy didn't include pthread either.

Comment: Can you try updating the compiler to GCC 4.9 or 5.1? Maybe you should try an example with std::promise, as that seems to be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this answer is still "unanswered," after talking with some people from `Lounge<C++>`, I think I can say that it's pretty obvious from the comments that **this is due to an implementation error either on MinGW/MinGW-w64's or pthread's part at the time.** Using gcc 4.9.1, MinGW-W64, the problem does not appear anymore. In fact, the program above appears to compile and run correctly even on a version *earlier* than 4.8.2 with POSIX threading.

I myself am not an expert, my guess is that the exact trip-up happens when the program appears to try to write to the same promise twice, which, I think, should be a big no-no, as an std::async should write its result only once (again, I'm not sure if I'm right here, and other comments and edits will most likely clarify).

Also, this may be a related problem: [std::future exception on gcc experimental implementation of C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930700/stdfuture-exception-on-gcc-experimental-implementation-of-c0x)

Comment: This bug report thread might be related for pthread: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12683

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that the crash disappears with gcc 4.9.1, MinGW-W64 (which was not available within a compiled Windows Qt distribution (the environment for my actual project) at the time I was asking the question)

Comment: It appears to be present in NetBSD 7.0 with GCC 4.8.4, too. Also see [NetBSD 7.0 amd64 and crash in DSA_Signature_Operation::raw_sign](https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/819).